# Select sum of a field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, activerecord

That title wasn't very descriptive; I wasn't sure how to shorten my question...

Let's say I have a table of `weightlifters`, with `name`, `pounds`, and `type_of_lift` as fields. This table has hundreds of entries in it. I want to retrieve the people with the 10 highest total pounds in the table. I've written the following:

```
Weightlifter.order("pounds DESC").limit(10)
```

This work fine, except for I want cumulative weights. So if a person is in the top 10 more than once, I don't want his name to be listed twice, I want to add the weights together and display them as a sum. So if I have:

```
"Johnny", "300", "Bench"
"Wesley", "295", "Bench"
"Johnny", "280", "Clean"
...
"Timmy", "150", "Curl"
```

I want to display Johnny with 580 pounds, instead of Johnny with 300 pounds and again later as Johnny with 280 pounds.

How is this done?

Ruby 1.9.3, Rails 3.2.6, SQLite3 3.6.20

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be something like this

```
Weightlifter.select('name, type_of_lift, sum(pounds) as pounds').
             group('name').
             order("sum(pounds) DESC").
             limit(10)
```

Here's a good guide: [ActiveRecord Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#group).

Comment: Okay, suppose I need the entire entry returned, not just the name. Then what?

Comment: @XMLSlayer: There are multiple entries for "Johnny" (your example), which one do you want to be returned?

Comment: It doesn't matter in my actual case; all the other fields are identical. This is just an example. I guess just the first will suffice; I can generalize from there.

Comment: @XMLSlayer: then add all other fields to select clause. See updated answer

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: I've copied your code exactly into the console, and it isn't working exactly as I need. It's not returning the total pounds, and it's still returning doubles of each high-ranking item. I get the following as output:

`[#<WeightLifter name: "Johnny", type_of_lift: "bench" #<WeightLifter name: "Wesley", type_of_lift "bench">, #<WeightLifter name: "Johnny", type_of_lift "clean">]`

For my first three outputs. As you can see, I still don't have access to total pounds acquired. And Johnny is still listed twice. Any ideas?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: Throws an error? `SQLite3::SQLException: aggregate functions are not allowed in the GROUP BY clause`

Comment: @XMLSlayer: stupid me. Why did I want to group by pounds? It should grouped by name, of course! Try again :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: Yeah! Woo hoo! I knew there was a way to do this haha, I'm just too new to know the methods in and out. Thanks a bunch! I want to clarify one thing real quick. Suppose the top 10 lifters are all unique, and a another lifter has all the records from 11-20. His lifts added together break the top 10. This code won't just stop once it hits 10, will it? It will continue through every entry first?

Comment: It will scan all records in the table, sum pounds and calculate correct top 10.

Comment: Thanks Sergio for your answer. This is an incredible piece of code

Answer (score 1):

```
# in your WeightLifter model
class Weightlifter < ActiveRecord

  attr_accessor :weight_total


# WeightLifterController

lifters = []

Weightlifter.order("pounds DESC").each do |lifter| 

  return lifters if lifters.count == 10

  if !lifters.collect{|a| a[:name] }.include?(lifter.name)
    lifters << lifter
    local_lifter = lifters.where(name: lifter.name).first
    local_lifter.weight_total = lifter.weight
  else
    local_lifter = lifters.where(name: lifter.name).first
    local_lifter.weight_total = local_lifter.weight_total + lifter.weight
  end

end
```

Comment: I thought of this already. This doesn't do anything to sum the weights together. It simply ignores any repeated names. I need the aggregate total.

Comment: Your edit throws an error for me in the console. `undefined method 'limit'`

Comment: Thanks for your help as well. This code would work as well (just make sure you modify the array itself, not just an element you pulled from it. Changing `local_lifter.weight_total` doesn't commit the change to the array), but I was looking for something along the lines of Sergio's code. Thanks though!